# How to json decode in php

Tags: php, json

How to json decode in php

```
{
    TestID": 1,
    UserID": 1,
    TotalAttempted": 1,
    TotalQuestion": 1,
    LeftQuestion": 1,
    CorrectQuestion": 1,
    IncorrectQuestion": 1,
    TimeTaken": 1,
    "msg": [
        {
            "QuestionID": 5,
            "IsTrue": 1,
            "GivenAnswer": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: use` json_decode` see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Ok thanks for your co-operating

Answer (score 2):

Reference:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
<?php
   $array = json_decode($json_variable,true);
  echo "<pre/>";print_r($array);
?>
```

Note:- Your json data have some missed `"`.

***Example with a valid json***:-https://eval.in/743659